# Find data before validate form request laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, validationrules

I want to update the data using the request form validation with a unique email role, everything works normally.
Assume I have 3 data from id 1-3 with url:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/update/3
```

Controller:

```
use App\Http\Requests\Simak\User\Update;
...
public function update(Update $request, $id)
{
    try {
        // UPDATE DATA
        return resp(200, trans('general.message.200'), true);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Ambil error
        return $e;
    }
}
```

FormRequest "Update":

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'user_akses_id' => 'required|numeric',
        'nama'          => 'required|max:50',
        'email'         => 'required|email|unique:users,email,' . $this->id,
        'password'      => 'required',
        'foto'          => 'nullable|image|max:1024|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg',
        'ip'            => 'nullable|ip',
        'status'        => 'required|boolean'
    ];
}
```

but if the updated id is not found eg:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/update/4
```

The response gets `The email has already been taken`.

What is the solution so that the return of the data is not found instead of validation first?

Comment: This should be working fine, make sure `$this->id` contains the id for which you are updating the data.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks like it should work fine, sharing a few things below that may help.

**Solution 1:** Check if `$this->id` contains the id you are updating for.

**Solution 2:** Try using the following changes, try to get the id from the URL segment.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'user_akses_id' => 'required|numeric',
        'nama'          => 'required|max:50',
        'email'         => 'required|email|unique:users,email,' . $this->segment(4),
        'password'      => 'required',
        'foto'          => 'nullable|image|max:1024|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg',
        'ip'            => 'nullable|ip',
        'status'        => 'required|boolean'
    ];
}
```

Sharing one more thing that may help you.

Some person uses `Request` keyword at the end of the request name. The `Update` sounds generic and the same as the method name you are using the request for. You can use `UpdateRequest` for more code readability.

Comment: Thanks for answering. in this case update method. everything was running properly, I got the ID. however the problem is not the id, but the ambiguous validation, because if I send a request with an id that is not available in the database with an email that is already available, what I get is not a "User not found" log, but the response is email already used. because it should check whether the user with the id exists or not, then the email validation :)

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is, you need a way to check if the record really exists or not in the form request. If that's the case create a custom rule that will check if the record exists or not and use that rule inside your request.

CheckRecordRule

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class CheckRecordRule implements Rule
{
   protected $recordId;

   public function __construct($id)
   {
       $this->recordId = $id;
   }

   public function passes($attribute, $value)
   {
       // this will check and return true/false
       return User::where('id', $this->recordId)->exists();
   }

   public function message()
   {
       return 'Record not found.';
   }
}
```

Update form request

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,' . $this->id.'|'. new CheckRecordRule($this->id),
    ];
}
```

So when checking for duplicate it will also check if the record really exists or not and then redirect back with the proper message.